# AngularJS binding checkboxes to model property

Tags: javascript, angularjs, checkbox

I have an AngularJS app with a list of users with an 'Edit' button beside each user. Each user has a number of subjects associated with them. When I click on 'Edit', it opens a form in which you can edit user details, and select associated subjects from a list of checkboxes. I'm trying to figure out how to bind the subject checkboxes so that the subjects which the 
user is already associated with are checked, and the rest are unchecked. Any suggestions appreciated.

My HTML:

```
<form name="UserEditForm">
 Name: <br /> <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.name"> <br />
{{name}}

Email: <br /> <input type="text" name="name" ng-model="user.email"> <br />
{{email}}

 <div class="control-group">
            <label class="control-label" for="inputSubjects">Subjects:</label>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label ng-repeat="subject in subjects" class="checkbox">
              <input type="checkbox" ng-checked="{user.subjects}"  name="selectedSubjects[]" value="{{subject.id}}" ng-model="subject.selected"> {{subject.name}}
              </label>
        </div>

<br />

<a ng-click="updateUser()" class="btn btn-small btn-primary">Save Changes</a>

</form>
```

My UserEditCtrl:

```
angular.module('myApp.controllers')
    .controller('UserEditCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams','SubjectsFactory', 'UserFactory', '$location',
    function ($scope, $routeParams, SubjectsFactory, UserFactory, $location) {

        // callback for ng-click 'updateUser':
        $scope.updateUser = function () {
            $scope.user.subjects = $scope.selection;
            UserFactory.update($scope.user);
            $location.path('/users');
        };

        // callback for ng-click 'cancel':
        $scope.cancel = function () {
            $location.path('/users');
        };

        $scope.user = UserFactory.show({id: $routeParams.userid});
        $scope.subjects = SubjectsFactory.query();

        $scope.selection = [];

    // helper method
    $scope.selectedSubjects = function selectedSubjects() {
      return filterFilter($scope.subjects, { selected: true });
    };

    // watch subjects for changes
    $scope.$watch('subjects|filter:{selected:true}', function (nv) {
      $scope.selection = nv.map(function (subject) {
        return subject.id;
      });
    }, true);


    }]);
```

Comment: Your code looks good, except for the `ng-checked` attribute on your input. Maybe try removing that?

Comment: Thanks- I've tried without it, the result is the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @jkinkead said, your code looks good, I fixed the ng-checked binding in accordance with your ng-model expression

Here's a simplified plunker : http://plnkr.co/edit/qaIBExtVbNdSXlQlbMym?p=preview

**EDIT 1:** I edited and improved the plunker to get closer to your case.

Comment: Is that what you wanted to do? I can edit the plunker if necessary.

Comment: thanks for the plunker. However, what I want to do is have the checkboxes 'prechecked' depending on what subjects the user is studying. Eg, if user1 is studying maths and physics, the maths and physics checkboxes should be already checked when I click on edit, but the other subject checkboxes should be unchecked and available for selection. I know how to do this with dummy data, by setting the 'selected' property to true in the scope. I just don't know how to do it with data returned from an api. Any suggestions on this appreciated!

Comment: I edited the plunker (same link, should be up to date). Please take a look at the comments in the JS. I also removed some attributes in the HTML : ng-checked isn't necessary beacuse ng-model on a checkbox is sufficient.

Comment: @glepetre, thank you, but that link doesn't work now?

Comment: Plunker website seems to have serious problems today :(

Comment: It does seem to be down- I'll keep checking back :-)

Comment: Hmmm. That looks great, but I don't understand how I can implement this with the api? The JSON returned from the api will not have a 'selected' property..

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/46770/discussion-between-glepretre-and-bookthief)